# How can i add the command "java" to bash?

Tags: bash

Im right now trying to execute Bukkit BuildTools on my Computer.
From tutorials I've learned that to do that i have to execute in the Programm "GIT-Bash" in the directory where I've put the 'BuildTools.jar' file the command 'java -jar BuildTools.jar.

The Problem is: when I try to do that GitBash and CMD tell me "bash: java: command not found". I know where the command is saved on my Computer. I just dont know how to tell GitBash where it can find it.

Thanks for help
Jonas

PS: Im using Win10 if thats helping the answer :)

Comment: Bash uses the `PATH` environment variable to find executables to run; adding the directory with your `java.exe` to the colon-separated list of directories in `PATH` will enable that executable to be found. That said, this is outside StackOverflow's scope -- the focus here is on *developing software*, vs configuring your system. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a better choice for this kind of question.

Comment: Official Java documentation on editing your PATH exists for some reason: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml